# Create R dataframe from single string containing elements and whitespace

Tags: r, string, dataframe, initializer, removing-whitespace

I have string that looks like this

```
string <- "\n\t\t\t1,2\n\t\t\t3,4\n\t\t"
```

And I need to create following data frame

```
1 2
3 4
```

One way is to use strsplit function, but it feels that there must be much better way of doing it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: To strip out the last line, `read.csv(text = trimws("\n\t\t\t1,2\n\t\t\t3,4\n\t\t"), header = FALSE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert a character string to a thing that behaves a bit like a file with `textConnection` and then feed it to `read.csv`:

```
> read.csv(textConnection(string),head=FALSE)
  V1 V2
1  1  2
2  3  4
3 NA NA
```

the stray tabs after the last newline produce that last line of NA values, you'd need to take care of those some way.

Comment: You can just use `read.csv(text=string, header=FALSE)` since it all gets passed through to `read.table` which has the `text=` argument. And that will save a whole 10 characters, which you can then spend on moonpies and pennywhistles.

Comment: I thought `textConnection` would be a more generic solution that could be applied anywhere text is in an object instead of a file. But `readr::read_csv` complains because its not binary and it doesn't have a `text=` argument.... base R ftw!